# What is this cello with a fret-board called?

Tags: instruments

What is this cello with fret board called?

Answer (score 2):

It is a form of modernist *viola da gamba* (or *viol* in english), just not held like this instrument is typically held (which would probably be hard with the form anyhow).

By the way the video does list the instrumentarium in the description.

Comment: I'd say, rather than "modernist," that even though the performer calls it (and probably tunes it like) a gamba, it's styled after a medieval vielle, with the flat headstock and such (which, yes, [is represented played in cello position and fretted](https://caslabs.case.edu/medren/medieval-instruments/vielle-medieval/)). Its morphology was so heterogenous, it amounts to little more than a catch-all for "medieval bowed string instrument."

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes, true. Tuning is like guitar here, not like a da gamba.

Comment: Not a gamba - almost all of which AFAIK are designed to be bowed and thus have a curved cross-section on the fingerboard.

Answer (score 1):

You must mean *not* the featured image of the video (which is a [lute-guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lute_guitar), the first instrument featured in the video), but the second instrument, which is an ***electric* viola da gamba**, appearing for the first time at [minute 0:03 - 0:06](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWIGbHhSsGs&t=3s):

[image: Electric Viola Da Gamba]

Though I haven't been able to find the precise make and model of the one he used, this 7-string version named [Biarnel Paw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ok4Z0y6wwA) is quite close in construction.

The frets came standard since very early on (see the [*Construction* section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viol#Construction) of the *Wikipedia* article).  We can see the much thicker *acoustic* Viola da Gamba [being introduced by Craig Trompeter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3NdlZdSwMg) who also described at length how it is different from a Cello.  Explanation about the frets and they are used at minute 1:55-2:50.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and also originally called an Arpeggione.

It is fretted and tuned like a six string guitar, but with a curved bridge so that it may be played with a bow like a cello.

Originated in the early 1800's in Vienna, Austria.

Comment: Not exactly. He does use a guitar tuning on the instrument, which is more akin to the arpeggione, but the shape the instrument is much more similar to a viola da gamba, also the bowhold is closer to the underhanded hold used on the da gamba than to the overhanded cello hold used on the Arpeggione. The viola da gamba originated in 15th century in Spain.

Comment: Not to mention, the whole point of this ["bardcore"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bardcore) vid is not to reference 19th cent Austria, but a sort of Renn-fair-style vague medievalism.